# how to reset form data after successfull axios post request

Tags: forms, validation, post, axios, alpine.js

I have modalform component made using Alpine js and axios for POST request.
But I cannot understand few things:

1. How to reset form data after succesfull POST request.
   I see error in console `TypeError: this.resetFields is not a function`
2. How to get errors to show them for the user if POST request is failed due to validation errors with 422 status code.
   I want to bind errors.message to AlpineJs variable errors and then show it on the webpage using `<p x-text="errors" class="text-red-600"></p>`, but `this.errors = error.message;` seems not working, because in AlpineJS devtools in Chrome errors variable doesn't change.

````
        function modalform() {
            return {
                mailTooltip: false,
                instagramTooltip: false,
                openModal: false,

                formData: {
                  name: '',
                  phone: '',
                  email: '',
                  address: '',
                  message: '',
                  _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },

                message: '',
                errors: '',
                loading: false,
                sent: false,
                buttonLabel: 'Send',

                resetFields() {
                        this.formData.name = '',
                        this.formData.phone = '',
                        this.formData.email = '',
                        this.formData.address = '',
                        this.formData.message = ''
                },
                
                submitData() {
                    this.buttonLabel = 'Sending...';
                    this.loading = true;
                    this.message = '';

                    axios.post('/modalform', this.formData)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        this.resetFields();
                        this.message = response.data.name;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        this.errors = error.message;
                    });

                },
            }
        }
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. If you use the old `function(response){...}` style, then `this` refers to the object it was called on (axios). However is you replace it with the arrow function, then `this` will refer to the first non-arrow function object, in this case: the Alpine.js component.

```
axios.post('/modalform', this.formData)
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.resetFields();
    this.message = response.data.name;
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.errors = error.message;
});
```

Comment: One more question. I handle POST data with Laravel validation and in case validation passed I return `return response()->json([ 'status'  => 'success', 'messageHeader'  => 'Your message sent!',  'messageContent' => 'We will contact you soon.' ]);`
And this response message I can reach `this.responseData = response.data;` to inform user. But if validation failed `this.errorData = error;` just gives me text `Error: Request failed with status code 422` and I don't see what is the reason of failure. But in Chrome devtools under network tab I see real error - too much symbols etc.

Comment: Based on [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/422-unprocessable-entity-in-laravel-with-vuejs?page=1&replyId=326398), the details of the validation error should be in the `error.response.data` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is absolutely correct.